# beginner django: next button acts as Submit

Tags: python, html, django

Disclaimer: I am new to python and django but have programmed in Drupal

I am developing a web-based Wizard (like on Microsoft Windows installation screens) with explanatory text followed by Previous and Next buttons (which are big green left and right arrows). So far, so good.

However, my current Wizard page (in project.html, loaded by my django apps views.py) now uses a form (instance of ModelForm) which asks the user to type in a "project" name, such as My Project. Normally, such an HTML form would use a Submit button, but because this is a Wizard, I need the Next button to act as the Submit button, hiding the Submit button entirely. Also, the arrow icons appear after the form ends.

How would you do this? Sure, I could use jquery, but is there a better pythonic or django way?

Some code:

```
#project.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

<h3><span>{% trans 'Project details' %}</span></h3>
<p>{% trans 'What is the name of this project?' %}
    <form method="post" action=""> 
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block buttonbar %}
<a href="/"><img src="/static/img/Button-Previous-icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Previous"><span>{% trans 'Previous' %}</span></a>
<a href="/profile"><img src="/static/img/Button-Next-icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Next button"><span>{% trans 'Next' %}</span></a>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try the Django Form Wizard, and also this seems to be more HTML related, you need an image button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use the Django Form wizard, in this case:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

Comment: I ended up using jquery. But thanks for the tip on the Django Form Wizard. Very nice!

Answer (score 3):

`<input type="submit" value="Next"/>`

This gives you a button with the value 'Next' which acts as a submit button. If this is not what you've wanted, rephrase your question and/or give an example of what action should take place after pressing next.